# How could I write a program for my iPod touch?

Tags: iphone, applet, ipod-touch

I don't want to register as Apple Developer and pay the Apple company before I know how to write a single line of code for iPod. How could I start writing a program for my iPod?

Is there a free way to write my own program and load it into my own iPod without paying the Apple company? It's so ridiculous that I bought my own iPod but cannot use it as I wish.

Thanks.

Comment: This could have EASILY been Googled. Much information is out there on how to get started.

Comment: You have already paid Apple: when you got your iPod, and your Mac, and your iPad, and your iTunes purchases, and your iWhatever.

Comment: You're welcome to do anything with your iPod Touch that was written on the box, the manuals it came with, the Apple web site that promoted it and the posters in the Apple store. I don't think the right to run your own programs at all costs was one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to http://developer.apple.com
2. Sign up
3. Download the software without paying

You only have to pay to get access to more support and for the right to ask Apple if they will put your app in their store.

Comment: You don't need to pay the developer fee (although you do need a Mac) to sign up, install Xcode and the SDK, start writing code, and run it on the *simulator*, and decide if it's something you want to pursue.

You *do* need to pay the $99 fee in order to install on any actual device, even your own for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to pay to download the iPhone SDK (which works on iPod touch devices as well), it's available for free on Apple's iOS SDK Developer Page (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/). You must have Mac OS X installed to run it, however.

In terms of learning, you can look through Apple's Documentation (available at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html), but the best tools for learning are definitely books. You should look into purchasing **Programming in Objective-C 2.0** by Stephen Kochan and **The iPhone Developer's Cookbook** by Erica Sadun.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the iPhone/iPod/iOS SDK.
2. Develop your application, test using the simulator.

You only need to pay for access to the App Store and for rights to load your application on a real device.

Comment: That's it. I am wondering if there's a way to load my program into my ipod only without paying the Apple company. It's just ridiculous that I bought my iPod but cannot use it as I want.

Comment: That's the way Apple things work: you trade complete control for a better out-of-the-box experience.

But you can stick it to the man and jailbreak it, installing an alternative application loader (usually Cydia) if you want. It's morally shady and possibly illegal in some countries though. But you'll have to ask Google about that :D

Comment: @smwikipedia: Thats what Android is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can register for free as a developer [here](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/). Without the tools and resources provided exclusively to members, you're going to have a very hard time getting started.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I wanted to do! I found the solution here:

http://ipodtoucher55.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-create-iphone-apps-in-flash-cs5.html

No need to pay Apple, no need to have a Mac, but you do need to know how to code in AS3 (which is too hard if you know some other languages)